# Spring Cache Abstraction

Tags: spring, ehcache

> Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager' for property 'cacheManager'

```
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager" p:cache-manager="ehcache"/>
<!-- Ehcache library setup -->
<bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean" p:config-location="classpath:com/spring/test/ehcache/config/ehcache.xml"/>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`p:cache-manager` won't work for a bean reference. Try this instead:

```
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager">
   <property name="cacheManager" ref="ehcache"/>
</bean>

<bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
   <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:com/spring/test/ehcache/config/ehcache.xml"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager" >
  <property name="cacheManager" ref="ehcache"/>
 </bean>
 <!-- Ehcache library setup -->
 <bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean" >  <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:com/citi/rel/document/services/ehcache/config/ehcache.xml"/>
 </bean>

This worker perfectly Thanks for the solution

Answer (score 6):

Or you can use the proper way of Spring p-namespace

```
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager"        p:cache-manager-ref="ehcache"/>
```